# Javascript Rich Text Editor and associated class to filter and clean the input?

Tags: richtextbox, xss, filtering, richtext, antixsslibrary

I realise there are several rich text editors for jQuery but I cannot find any that have an associated class that does the filtering and cleaning required to accept the input into a database.

Does such a class exist?

I am particularly interested for a PHP library, but .NET would be interesting too.

Answer (score 0):

If you would use FCKeditor it would allow to you get clean HTML or XHTML (editor.GetXHTML()) which you could then write into DB.

Actually it's not that much important what you write into DB, because usially you write original HTML (you can always strip from it saspicious tags if needed). In order to prevent XSS attacks it is essential to properly encode content before displaying it on the web-page. For .NET there is [AntiXSS library](http://www.codeplex.com/AntiXSS) for that at CodePlex.com

For PHP you may want to look at the following libraries:

- [Zend_Filter](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.filter.html)
- [HTML Sanitizer](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/3746.html)
- [PHP Input Filter](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/2189.html)

And also this article:

- [Avoiding XSS security attacks to sites that use HTML editors](http://devzone.zend.com/article/1752-Avoiding-XSS-security-attacks-to-sites-that-use-HTML-editors)